# How to use i18n fallback in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to prepare/prevent for the situation when i want to set a locale which isn't supported yet.

> So i load .json file, there i can set a language. **When i don't have
>   the language, how can i set a fallback to the default one?**

Of course, i can easily prevent this with a own function, but i rather would like to use a provided one.

I can set the default locale by:

```
I18n.defaultLocale = "language";
```

Is there a fallback method provided in JavaScript which i can call?

EDIT: My implementation looks like this:

```
self.localisation = I18n.locale;
if (I18n.translations.hasOwnProperty(self.localisation)) 
    I18n.locale ? self.localisation : "en";
```

The actual question is:

Is there a library call? I prefer to use API and not my own methods in those cases.

Comment: You'll have to show us your code.  Without seeing any code, the logic seems simple enough.  Try to load the desired language, if that fails, load the default language.  But, without seeing your code, that's about all we can suggest.  There is nothing built into Javascript to do this for you.

Comment: A library call for what? Getting the string `en` returned?

Comment: It could be that there is something like isTranslationProvided("language"), couldn't be?